# c# File Copy From Current Folder to Special Forder

Tags: c#

As titled i want to copy an executable file to another folder so here is my Code  :

```
    public static void CopyThis()
    {
        File.Copy(Convert.ToString(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), Convert.ToString(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + @"\fileexe.exe"), true);



        File.SetAttributes(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + "\\NipClient.exe", FileAttributes.Hidden);

        File.SetAttributes(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + "\\NipClient.exe", FileAttributes.System);

        File.SetAttributes(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles) + "\\NipClient.exe", FileAttributes.ReadOnly);

    }
```

But it always throw an exception :

```
Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\fileexe.exe' is denied.
```

Notice that i v Already Tried to run the application with admin privilieges .

Comment: Does the "C:\Program Files\fileexe.exe" already exist?  is it running or locked by another process?

Comment: You can not copy paste move anything in some part of path Program Files one of them, so you have to use a place where you have access right

Comment: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` is a string.  You're converting a string to a string.  In fact, everything you're converting to a string is already a string.  Also, writing to Program Files is bad, and the OS will do everything it can to prevent you from doing so.  So don't.  Back up.  What are you trying to accomplish by writing to Program Files?

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your comments  I v jjust tried to use the same code with specialfolder => Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures  and its actually worked with the same code for your questions No there is no file existing with the same name  already put an File.exist() Condition

Answer (score 0):

And using `Path.Combine()` to create pathes is better way :)

Comment: Hi m a bit confused cause when i tried to use another special folder as Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures it worked with the same code